# Long execution time when running PySpark-SQL on hadoop cluster?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set of weather data and I am trying to query it to get average lows and average highs for each year. I have no problem submitting the job and getting the desired result but it is taking hours to run. I thought it would run much faster, Am I doing something wrong or is it just not as fast as I'm thinking it should be?

The data is a csv file with over 100,000,000 entries. 
THe columns are date, weather station, measurement(TMAX or TMIN), and value

I am running the job on my university's hadoop cluster, I don't have much more information than that about the cluster.

Thanks in advance!

```py
import sys
from random import random
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonPi")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    file = sys.argv[1]
    lines = sc.textFile(file)
    parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    obs = parts.map(lambda p: Row(station=p[0], date=int(p[1]) , measurement=p[2] , value=p[3]  )  ) 
    weather = sqlContext.createDataFrame(obs)
    weather.registerTempTable("weather")


    #AVERAGE TMAX/TMIN PER YEAR
    query2 = sqlContext.sql("""select SUBSTRING(date,1,4) as Year, avg(value)as Average, measurement
                                from weather
                                where value<130 AND value>-40 
                                group by measurement, SUBSTRING(date,1,4) 
                                order by SUBSTRING(date,1,4) """)

    query2.show()
    query2.rdd.map(lambda x: ",".join(map(str, x))).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs:/user/adduccij/tmax_tmin_year.csv")
    sc.stop()
```

Comment: try out the suggestions I mentioned. If you provide some more details e.g. # executors and which part of code is actually taking long, maybe I can provide more input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that spark job in fact started in cluster (and not local) mode. e.g. If you're using yarn, then job is launched in 'yarn-client' mode.

If that's true, then make sure you've provided enough #executors/cores/ executor and driver memory. You can get the actual cluster/job information from either the resource manager (e.g. yarn) page or from spark context (sqlContext.getAllConfs).

100Mil records is not that small. Let's say each record is 30 bytes, still the overall size is 3gb and that can take a while if you only have a handful of executors.

Let's say that the above suggestions do not help, then try to find out which part of the query is taking long. Few speed up tips are:

- Cache the weather dataframe
- Break the query into 2 parts: 1st part does group by, and output is cached
- 2nd part does order by
- instead of coalesce, write the rdd with default shards and then do a mergeFrom to get your csv output from shell.

Comment: Breaking query apart and caching helped significantly. Can you explain the fourth bullet a little more, "instead of coalesce, write the rdd with default shards and then do a mergeFrom to get your csv output from shell."

Comment: ok great. 4th point was about .coalesce(1) that you do before writing to text file. That essentially causes your rdd to get redistributed into 1 partition before writing to hdfs. That might be a slow operation as well. If you're doing that so that you get only 1 file in output, then same thing can be achieved by writing the rdd as it is in the hdfs and then running following to merge output in single file: hdfs dfs -getmerge /user/adduccij/tmax_tmin_year.csv single_file_out.csv